# Why is XCode giving me UITableViewController templates without the normal methods?

Tags: ios, swift

I've started trying some build-a-blog-reader tutorials and noticed that when I add a new UITableViewController file to control a new tableview, it doesn't give me all the methods.

All the tutorials walk me through adding a new file, selecting Cocoa Touch Class, then giving it a name and selecting UITableViewController from the presets. Yet my default file doesn't even have the viewDidLoad function by default, let alone all the methods that seem to flow in via these tutorial videos.

It seems I've done a few of these in the past and I actually had access to those, so did I turn something off inadvertently? How do I get it back? Or is this part of some new XCode update?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are adding a new Cocoa Touch class, make sure you're under the *iOS* section of the options, and not the *OS X* ones.

[image]

For some reason, even when you're working on an iOS project and you try to add a new file, the options will take you to the OS X files and not the iOS ones. So just go to "Source" under "iOS" and when you create your Cocoa Touch class from there it will correctly import UIKit instead of Cocoa and it will also include the necessary UITableViewController methods.

Comment: From the comment on other answer it definitely seems like this is the problem. (OP mentions there is `import Cocoa`)

Comment: Yeah I'm 99% certain this is the problem. It happens to me more often than I'd like. I should probably open a bug report regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Select **Cocoa Touch Class** instead of **Swift File** when you create a new file.

Comment: I do exactly that and here's the entire contents of the file it then creates for me:


import Cocoa

class TableViewTest: UITableViewController {

}

Comment: Is Xcode the latest version? Maybe the file template is broken or missing. If so, it might be fixed if you reinstall Xcode.

Comment: @Chris Before you reinstall, take a look at my answer. I have this problem too and I believe it is a bug with XCode.

Comment: Dude! Totally correct. How did I not notice it was defaulting to the OS X tab? I actually did just reinstall, but this worked. Thanks!